# Launch an app from applet in Windows 8 & Java 7

Tags: java, security, applet, java-7, runtime.exec

Before updating to java 7, I could launch an app from an applet using this code.

```
public class RIS extends Applet
{
  public void init()
  {
    String rutamedical = getParameter("dir");
    String parametro = getParameter("id");

    Runtime app = Runtime.getRuntime();
    try {
      app.exec(rutamedical + " " + parametro);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      JFrame ventana = new JFrame("Prueba JDialog");
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(ventana, "Problema al ejecutar la aplicacion");
    }
  }
}
```

Yesterday, I tried it from Win 8 and Java 7 and It throws an exception. It doesn't work. If I try it with Win 8 and Java 6 it works, and with Win 7 and Java 7 works as well.

Any idea or suggestion about what happen?

I got this Exception:

```
'Cannot run program "H:\Program": CreateProcess error = 2,' System can't find the specified file.
```

The path would be:

```
H:\Program Files (x86)\VM MEDICAL WORKSTATION\CONEXIONRIS\Conexion Ris.exe
```

..but it seems not to find it, but with Java 6 I had no troubles.

### Update

@AndrewThompson this is the HTML I'm using launching the applet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="es" lang="es">
    <head>
        <title>Paso de variables Javascript entre páginas</title>
        <script language="javascript">
              function gup( name ){
                var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
                var regex = new RegExp ( regexS );
                var tmpURL = window.location.href;
                var results = regex.exec( tmpURL );
                if( results == null )
                    return"";
                else
                    return results[1];
            }
            function kill(variable){
                var idx = variable.toString().indexOf("%20");
                while (idx != -1) {
                    variable = variable.toString().replace("%20"," ");
                    idx = variable.toString().indexOf("%20", idx);
                }
                return variable;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script language="javascript">
            
            document.write("<APPLET CODE='appletris.RIS' ARCHIVE='applets/AppletRIS.jar' width=0 height=0>");
            var dir = gup( 'dir' );
            dir = kill(dir);
            alert("Alerta html:" + dir)
            document.write("<PARAM NAME='dir' VALUE='"+dir+"'>");
            var id = gup( 'id' );
            id = kill(id);
            document.write("<PARAM NAME='id' VALUE='"+id+"'>");
            
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I need to run from the applet in client machine an app in the next path:

```
D:\Program Files (x86)\VM MEDICAL WORKSTATION\CONEXIONRIS\Conexion Ris.exe
```

But it seems to have troubles with blank spaces.
"dir" it's the path of the app I have to launch --> It's stored on the BD.
I can't post you any Exception Information more because with this applet Im not able to see the java console.

It may would be easy to do it in other way, but I have no too much time to develop other things, and I know that it breaks security rules allowing to run and "*.exe" from an applet.

Comment: *"It throws an exception"*  What exception?  Copy/paste the output as an [edit to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16237124/edit).  **Change `} catch (Exception e) {` to `} catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace();` first.**

Comment: A sand-boxed applet would not be able to call `Runtime.exec()` so I expect you'll see an `AccessControlException` with the addition of a stack trace.  BTW 1) The `dir` command would not show directories on the server, if that is the intent. 2) For file operations on the client, use the more robust `File` API.

Comment: Thank for your time @AndrewThompson I get this exception:
'Cannot run program "H:\Program": CreateProcess error = 2, The System can't find the specified file'. It seems to have troubles with the path, but before (with java6) It used to work.

Comment: @AndrewThompson this is the HTML I'm using launching the applet: